# Allowing both hover and select state on a section / component

Tags: hover, select, states

**Do you think allowing both hover and select on a component makes sense in the bellow context?**

- The tool is a drag & drop application builder (UI builder).
- Configuring objects (sections in the page or components such as buttons, checkboxes, inputs, etc) is done by first selecting the object in the page.
- The user can always select another object or multiple by also clicking on Command.
- Each object also has a hover state

I was thinking that once something is selected it doesn't make sense to have the hover state anymore, as hover is an indicator that it can be selected/interacted with. (once selected objects can also be dragged and repositioned in the layout)

Would you approach this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once selected, the object can still be interacted with by dragging, so it still makes sense to keep providing the affordance (on hover) that this object can be interacted with.